# Captcha load only on page Refresh

Tags: php

I'm experience a very frustrating problem that I can't seem  to find the root cause. I'm trying to implement a simple captcha on found here: https://github.com/claviska/simple-php-captcha

The code is unaltered from github and added to my website per the instructions.  When using IE 8, the image is displayed as a broken image but if I refresh the page (F5), the image magically appears. Firefox and Chrome and even Safari has no issues displaying the image. I have no idea why it's displayed as broken upon entering the webpage. I've spent a couple days researching and am quite lost.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
I've been watching the php logs closely and notice that the function seems to be called twice.  It seems when entering the page, everything is fine and the image is generated. However, between entering the page and the final load, the function is called again and the browser is trying to display the first image the script created which as already been destroyed at that point. This only happen in IE which is why I am so confused.

Code used to test:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
include("captcha.php");
$_SESSION['captcha'] = captcha();
?>

<html>
<body>
<table>
     <tr>
        <td width="45%"><?php echo ('<img src="' . $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src'] . '" alt="CAPTCHA" />'); ?></p></td>
        <td width="4%">:</td>
        <td><input name="captcha" type="text" id="captcha" required><b><font color="red"> *</font></b></td>
     </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My money is on `$_SESSION['captcha']['image_src']`; what's the contents of that?

Comment: The function itself returns: /captcha.php?_CAPTCHA&amp;t=0.55984800+1346094060

Comment: Why using `$_SESSION = array();`? By doing this, you are resetting `$_SESSION` var to an `array`. I think you should write so: `if(!session_id()) session_start();`, just that. Besides, I could not understand the exact problem with IE.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild hunch and it might not work. Try changing your code to this:

```
session_start();
include("captcha.php");
$captcha = captcha();
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha['code'];
session_write_close();
```

Then inside your HTML, refer to the URL as `$captcha['image_src']`. Trying to make sure this is not a session locking issue.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  same results :(. Image will only display on the refresh.

Comment: @user1628449 then you should check whether `captcha.php` is actually reading the session properly, using `file_put_contents()` so that it doesn't affect the image being sent by it.